# A Polymorphism Problem

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism

it works when :

```
list<ItemFixed> XYZ::List()
{
        list<Item> items = _Browser->GetMusic();
        list<ItemFixed> retItems = _Converter->Convert (items);
        return retItems;
}
```

but not :

```
list<ItemFixed> XYZ::List()
{
        return _Converter->Convert (_Browser->GetMusic());
}
```

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work? Explain you problem please. We can't you run your code. It's not complete.

Comment: What is the "Convert" function and what is _Converter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you passing the `list<Item>` as non-const reference to Convert function? In that case it will not compile as you can not pass temporary object by non-const reference in C++.

Comment: Modify the Convert function to either take parameters by value or by const reference. I think you get some error like: 
test.cpp:36: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::list<Item, std::allocator<Item> >&' from a temporary of type 'std::list<Item, std::allocator<Item> >'
test.cpp:23: error: in passing argument 1 of `std::list<ItemFixed, std::allocator<ItemFixed> > convert(std::list<Item, std::allocator<Item> >&)'